# Yii Booster - td cell height when contains progress bar

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, progress-bar

I'm creating app with Yii and YiiBooster. When I put a TbProgress widget into a `td` cell - it's height seems to have some kind of bottom padding (like 20-30px). It looks pretty bad as it causes my table rows to be higher than they should.

There was a `margin-bottom` defined to `40px` (in `bootstrap.css` file) but I removed it - it is still to high.

Anyone knows where can I change it?

Here is my code:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'invite-grid',
    'type' => 'striped condensed',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'idProject',
        'name',
        array(
            'header' => 'Postęp',
            'value' => function($data)
            {
                Controller::widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbProgress', array(
                    'percent' => ($data->projectInvites +1 )/ $data->projectMaxInvites * 100,
                    ));
            },
            'htmlOptions' => array (
                'style' => ''
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn'
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Because Yii is PHP based framework and the bootstrap (YiiBooster wrapper) is in PHP too? Plus the code above is also PHP.

Comment: Why the hell did you comment this Ferdi ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had to add `margin-bottom: -20px' to the code:

```
Controller::widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbProgress', array(
    'percent' => $data->projectInvites == 0 ?  0 : 
                 ($data->projectConfirms / $data->projectInvites) * 100,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'style' => 'height: 20px; margin-bottom: -20px',
        ),                          
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define `margin-bottom:0 !important;` to any css file inside your page to the class of that element.

Did you clear the asset directory after change bootsrap.css, you must if you want to changes to affect. May be that was the problem.

Look for padding to parent element or the same element of, may be there is padding not margin.

Comment: I'll try to manually add `margin...`. 
I cleared the assets to reload the bootstrap.css (altough I enabled reloading assets on every request for development).

The weird thing is that it is not the progress bar that is to high but the container `td` (I inspected that using FireBug). Unfortunately there is no direct class assigned to that td.